# Run add-in without showing taskpane?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have an add-in working (on Word for Mac).  All functionality runs in the background, so there is no interaction with the UI exposed in the taskpane.  However, if I close the taskpane, the add-in functionality is removed.

Is there a way to remove the taskpane so that the add-in functionality will run in the background?  Currently, the taskpane is just a waste of screen space...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'd appreciate the green tick if it has answered your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of doing that unfortunately. Suresh's answer is referring to Function Files and add-in commands, but that requires manual invocation and doesn't support the background tasks.

That means - if you want a user action to do something but no real UI is needed / Functions are the way to go. But if you want a background process running (checking if something has changed periodically) - you'll need the TaskPane.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you just need to tell you add-in to work on [shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) as per Microsoft add-in documentation. I achieved this my adding some tags in manifest.xml file. See the attachment below, but I would highly recommend you [shared runtime documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime).

[image]

NOTE: When you change your manifest.xml, your add-in often does not show changes when you run again, you might have to clear your Office application cache to get those changes.(This got frustrated for me).

**

*And you have to upload new manifest.xml with changes to the Marketplace offers and so that it appear on the AppSource as well.*

**

Answer (score 0):

You can make your add-in as UI-less add-in, which runs in background. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands) is the documentation on types of app commands (add-in buttons).  If your HTML file is empty already, change the [action type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/action#xsitype) from ShowTaskpane to ExecuteFunction. Include the HTML link as [FunctionFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile) and add a function, which can handle the event argument.