# How to debug ExecuteFunctions for word add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm implementing a functionality which runs in background(without **Taskpanel**), where I can POST the word document data to REST API through the **ExecuteFunctions**. my question here is How can I debug the Function file? I tried printing through the console logs and also tried to debug through **F12** and Visual studio tools, but didn't work. I have created word add-in using **YO Office** generator.

Comment: I'd appreciate the green tick if the suggested solution has solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as is, simplest way of debugging the functions is through the Web experience (https://onedrive.live.com), where they will print stuff on the console.

You should probably check out this answer though: [Run add-in without showing taskpane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943972/run-add-in-without-showing-taskpane)

You really can't run background tasks without having a TaskPane. Functions are meant to just plainly execute something **and exit**. That means; upon clicking the Function button, you can make a request and upload some data, but you can't really keep a connection open and upload periodically after just one click.