# Excel JS React - Run Code without opening Taskpane

Tags: reactjs, office-js

I have an Excel plugin written in React using the Office/Excel Javascript API.  I'm having the following challenges:

- I'm trying to create a global click event that detects a cell click and looks for a Binding
- If a Binding is available, a specific Taskpane should be opened
- The problem is the onSelectionChanged event handler only works when a Taskpane is open.
- When the Taskpane closes, the event stops from working again
- The manifest.xml file is configured with "ShowTaskpane" Actions which opens up task panes.

How do you initiate and keep an onSelectionChanged event alive in the Excel document?

See below for my index.js code.

```
import 'office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.min.css';
import App from './components/App';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { initializeIcons } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = 'Excel Plugin';

const render = (Component) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route
                        path="/:token"
                        component={({ match, location }) => {
                            return <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} match={match} location={location} />;
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </Router>
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('container')
    );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.initialize = () => {
    //Create global click event

    Excel.run(async function (context) {
        context.workbook.onSelectionChanged.add(handleChange);
        return context.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandlerFunction);

    function handleChange(e) {
        console.log('Clicking cell!');

        Excel.run(async function (context) {
            let range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
            range.values = 'Clicked!';

            return context.sync();
        });
    }

    function errorHandlerFunction(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    render(App);
};

Office.onReady = () => {
    Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);
};

/* Initial render showing a progress bar */
render(App);

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./components/App', () => {
        const NextApp = require('./components/App').default;
        render(NextApp);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with shared runtime, add-in can continue listen the event after taskpane closes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/show-hide-add-in?view=excel-js-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your add-in will run code for ribbon buttons, custom functions, and the task pane in separate JavaScript runtime environments. This creates limitations such as not being able to easily share global data, and not being able to access all CORS functionality from a custom function.

However, you can configure your Excel add-in to share code in the same JavaScript runtime (also referred to as a shared runtime). This enables better coordination across your add-in and access to the task pane DOM and CORS from all parts of your add-in.

With shared runtime, Your add-in can continue running code after the task pane is closed.

This the article to explain how to [configure shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 4th point, "When the Taskpane closes, the event stops from working again", I had a worked around to convert my configuration to [shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime). To keep running the functionality even when user close the Taskpane, I have added some configurations in manifest.xml file, like below:

[image]

[Run add-in without showing taskpane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943972/run-add-in-without-showing-taskpane/77064532#77064532)